# Documenting classes with doxygen

Tags: c++, doxygen

I am trying to follow [these doxygen examples](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html#docexamples), but nothing shows up. I run 
`doxygen Doxyfile`, and check the `index.html` file, but nothing is there. Only stuff that is in my `mainpage.dox` file, nothing to do with any classes. Ideally I'd have a class list, with this particular class I documented in it.

Perhaps it's my file structure. Does Doxygen just recurisvely search the root directory, or does it look for files with a special tag?

Comment: You have to tell it which files to include in your Doxyfile.  Look at the documentation to find out which configuration option it is.  Check this link: http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/starting.html#step1

Comment: @AnonMail playing around with the INPUT and FILE_PATTERNS tagnames doesn't do anything. Their default values should work, though. What made it work was setting `RECURSIVE              = YES` thanks for the help

Comment: Are you giving the full path names?  Or running doxygen in the directory where your code resides?  Why not post your Doxyfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I had to use both the @class parameter, as well as a brief description of the Class before that class was listed in the Class section of my generated documentation.

Comment: Check also the Doxyfile settings `HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES` and `EXTRACT_ALL`

Comment: Those are both pretty brute-force ways of solving the issue, especially the EXTRACT_ALL setting.